# What's a Class F cargo compartment?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, easa-regulations, aircraft-certification, cargo

Apparently, the Aviation Traders folks worked with EASA to define a special type of cargo compartment, known as a class F, during their work on [Iron Maiden's touring airplane](http://www.atl.aero/ironmaiden).  Just what is a Class F cargo compartment, and how does it differ in safety properties from the large class B compartments used on earlier combi configured aircraft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here in this amendment to the EASA CS-25](https://easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/NPA%202008-10.pdf) it says on page 4:

> ... for a new Class B cargo
>   compartment definition as well as design criteria for a new Class F cargo compartment
>   type. This latter class of compartment was introduced because whilst it was concluded
>   that manual fire fighting was not feasible for larger compartments, alternatives other
>   than just the existing Class C were identified.

And a bit further on page 5 (emphasis mine) :

> ... Further, a new Class F cargo
>   compartment definition is added, **which is not limited in size and which provides the
>   means to control or extinguish a fire without requiring a crewmember to enter the
>   compartment.** This proposed Class F compartment standard accommodates the carriage
>   of large amounts of baggage and cargo loads on Combi aeroplanes as well as in
>   compartments of smaller sizes exceeding the new Class B definition. New aeroplanes
>   designs can take advantage from the variable solutions under the Class F definitions to
>   ensure an acceptable level of fire protection.

And more concrete:

> The AMC further provides guidance for usage of other fire
>   protection means in the new Class F compartment such as Fire Containment Covers
>   (FCC) or Containers rather than having a liner installed to contain a fire and to protect
>   the critical systems and structure of the aeroplane.

I guess it's meant to allow storage of cargo in non-cargo areas (which do not have the adequate fire protection measures such as liners) if other non-traditional measures are installed (such as the Fire Containment Covers)